Why doesn't the crew dragon spacecraft of Polaris dawn mission appear to have a launch escape system?

All the crew Dragon spacecraft of SpaceX have a launch escape system powered by super Draco engines in case of an anomaly.
But the on the spacecraft of the Polaris dawn mission, the Dracos appear to be missing - as seen in the picture from SpaceX X handle.
Why is this the case?

Looks identical to previous launches to me https://x.com/johnkrausphotos/status/1577303100213411841 ? What exactly makes you think there are no super dracos?

On earlier Crew Dragon missions, the area below the SuperDracos was gray, making it visually obvious there was thermal protection in that area. On the last few missions (at least Crew 7 and Polaris Dawn) that area has been painted white.

The SuperDraco thrusters are there they are just not easily visible. Crew Dragon SuperDraco thrusters are difficult to see in most photos because of the covers in place to protect them. This photo of Endeavour in final processing prior to its inaugural flight shows them more clearly.

Crew Dragon Endeavour (NASA)

The seals of the covers are apparently filled as a final step which tends to make them disappear in photos taken from a distance.
